# Must declare the scalar variable "@start" WPF C# application

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am working with the WPF application with C# and connecting with SQL Server. I created a stored procedure in SQL Server which runs fine, but I can't pass the date value from my application.

In my WPF application, the user can choose a Truck model, select start and end date, press the button, and get the result of the total earned money. But I can only pass the truck model. The date doesn't go through and gives me an error that I must declare the scalar variable.

Here is my SQL Server procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getTotalRentForTruckModel] 
    @p0 varchar(50),
    @start date,
    @end date
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
    SELECT 
        [TruckModel-PB].ModelID, 
        SUM([TruckRental-PB].TotalPrice) AS TotalPrice
    FROM
        [TruckRental-PB]
    INNER JOIN 
        [IndividualTruck-PB] ON [TruckRental-PB].TruckID = [IndividualTruck-PB].TruckID 
    INNER JOIN 
        [TruckModel-PB] ON [IndividualTruck-PB].TruckModelID = [TruckModel-PB].ModelID
    WHERE
        [TruckModel-PB].Model = @p0 
        AND [TruckRental-PB].RentDate >= @start 
        AND [TruckRental-PB].ReturnDate <= @end
    GROUP BY
        [TruckModel-PB].ModelID
END
```

I can execute this procedure in SQL Server, enter values for the parameters, and get the results.

The data types in the SQL Server table: `RentDate` and `ReturnDate` are of type `date`.

My function from WPF application:

```
public static List<Total> getTotalPriceForSelectedTruckModel( string model, DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    using (DAD_TatianaContext ctx = new DAD_TatianaContext())
    {               
        return ctx.Total.FromSqlRaw("getTotalRentForTruckModel @p0,@start,@end", model, start, end).ToList();
    }
}
```

And code behind user entry:

```
private void saleBetweenDates_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string model = modelComboBox.Text;
    DateTime startDate = startDatePicker.SelectedDate.Value;
    DateTime endDate = endDatePicker.SelectedDate.Value;

    try
    {
        gridTrucks.ItemsSource = DAO.getTotalPriceForSelectedTruckModel(model, startDate, endDate);               
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Also is it possible to get only calculated value from SQL to my system, not the object? I do not know how to call it without creating another entity in my system.

Comment: Side point: consider using short meaningful table aliases to make your query more readable

Answer (score 0):

In order to run the stored procedure, you need to [add an execute statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#passing-parameters):

```
return ctx
  .Total
  .FromSqlRaw(
    "EXECUTE dbo.getTotalRentForTruckModel {0}, {1}, {2}", 
    model, 
    start, 
    end)
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you, Markus, I just had to add commas between {0}, {1}, {2} and I got value to my application

Comment: @TatianaPasechnik you're welcome. I've added the commas in the answer.

Comment: You actually don't need `EXEC` if it's the first statement in the batch